# Rails 5: Render very slow for first time (rb-notify: inotify event queue has overflowed)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

When I get `localhost:3000/` first time when after run `rails s`.
It render slow (over 5min) to render for first time.
When i look console, it display:

```
E, [2018-07-27T10:29:56.993181 #30765] ERROR -- : run() in thread failed: inotify event queue has overflowed.:\n /home/abc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.5/bundler/gems/rb-inotify-be4cf88b4dab/lib/rb-inotify/event.rb:120:in `initialize'
```

Full console here: https://gist.github.com/anhdayem818/d832da6bcbdd3a05eea37a603e7c9139

I try edit config in file `/etc/sysctl.conf` :

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 999999
fs.inotify.max_queued_events = 999999
fs.inotify.max_user_instances = 999999
```

And change version gem `rb-inotify` to :

`gem 'rb-inotify', github: 'e2/rb-inotify', branch: 'misc_bugfixes'` 
But not don't work for me. Please anyone can guide me solve this bug.
Thanks Anyone.